# Paypal integration for iOS

Tags: paypal, ios8, xcode6

We are building a iPhone application which includes paypal integration. Our application is simple buyer-seller iPhone application. We need to make a sinlge payment(buyer to seller) using paypal iOS sdk.

I have gone through the documentation. When login screen from sdk is launched, we need to log in with buyers's creadentials. However, I have not understood or rather confused if "merchantName" is where we are suppose to mention seller's paypal credential (email).

Answer (score 1):

"Merchant Name" is the name of the application provided to https://developer.paypal.com/developer/applications when you set up your application.

Note that peer-to-peer operations are not supported by the SDK.